# Looping with step 10 in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I run the below code to get the matrix a filled with the values from 0 to 2062630 alternatively with step that is. a(1) should be 0, a(2) 10 etc. or simply a should contain 0,10,20,30,40,......,2062630. But insted the code gives the matria with the value 2062630 in each element of the matrix a.

```
for i=1:length(x)
for j=0:10:2062637
a(i,:)=j;
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did not understand how the `colon` operator works, it already generates the matrix you want.

```
a=0:10:2062637
```

Comment: I need a matrix of 410874x1?

Comment: Another magic number appearing out of nowhere. Why `410874`? How should the matrix be filled. Maybe give a small example.

Comment: I have 410874 frames each of which I want to map between a time limit between 0 and 2062637 with a length of 10ms for each frame.

Comment: @chris: That's not what your question says. It's bad form to change the question entirely after posting. If you have important details it should be in the question. You question is essentially one of interpolation.

Comment: Okay, my bad. will have to explain the whole thing in a new question I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you want your code to produce, but you may not need any `for` loops. Instead you can use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
a = repmat(0:10:2062637,[length(x) 1]);
size(a)
```

This will create a matrix `a` with `length(x)` rows, each of which is `0:10:2062637`. It's also possible that you're also trying to create the transpose of this:

```
a = repmat((0:10:2062637).',[1 length(x)]);
size(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, if you want a vector or a matrix? Also I don't know what `x` is.

You could try:

```
count=1; 
for j=0:10:2062637 
  a(count)=j; 
  count=count+1; 
end
```

Which returns exactly the same thing as the solution proposed by @Daniel:

```
a=0:10:2062637
```